# How extract all the json content as a attribute in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have some flowfiles and their contents are json like this:

```
{"Message": "...", "Id":"122", "Size":"123"}
```

I would like to extract this whole json as an attribute in flowfile.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ExtractText` processor and add a new property as `ff_content` = `(.*)`